# Use "useradd" in script gives me error (access denied)

Tags: bash, scripts

this is my first post here. Im working in a homework for my scripting class and I have a question

```
#!/bin/bash

#Creacion de usuarios

VAR1="USERNAME"
VAR2="PASS"
VAR3="marieg"
VAR4="Test1"
VAR5="Test2"
VAR6="Test3"
VAR7="Test4"

echo "Indique los usuarios que quiera crear"

echo "$VAR3"

grep "$VAR3" /etc/passwd

echo "El usuario "$VAR3" ya existe, por favor elija otro nombre de usuario"

echo "$VAR4"
echo "$VAR5"
echo "$VAR6"
echo "$VAR7"

sudo useradd -p 'mkpasswd "$VAR4"' -d /home/"$VAR4" -m -g users -s /bin/bash "$VAR4"
sudo useradd -p 'mkpasswd "$VAR5"' -d /home/"$VAR5" -m -g users -s /bin/bash "$VAR5"
sudo useradd -p 'mkpasswd "$VAR6"' -d /home/"$VAR6" -m -g users -s /bin/bash "$VAR6"
sudo useradd -p 'mkpasswd "$VAR7"' -d /home/"$VAR7" -m -g users -s /bin/bash "$VAR7"
```

The idea of the 4 last lines is to create 4 diferent users.
When I use useradd WHITOUT sudo I got an "access denied" so I thought that adding sudo would solve my problem.... now is asking for my password every time I run the script.

Is there a way to use "useradd" in a script without having an access denied error or beign asked for the password if I choose use sudo?

thanks!

Comment: No...  You have to use `sudo` because creating a new user requires system administrator privileges.  And those privileges are protected by a password -- you need to authenticate again after logging in.  You can do an `sudo su` and that changes yourself to the root user.  But then every command you execute after that (until you type `exit`) is being executed as the administrator.  I find it strange that a scripting assignment would be testing this...seems a bit irrelevant.  Perhaps you won't be deducted marks for this `sudo` part since it's somewhat unavoidable.

Comment: Read `man sudoers`. You can configure passwordless `sudo` access to the `adduser` command. I advise using the absolute path (starting at `/`) for `addusers`, both in the `sudoers` file and your script.

Comment: @Ray DO NOT USE `sudo su`, use `sudo -i` instead.

Comment: @Emoji Uh...sure...but you don't have to use all caps, you know.  A more polite, "I think if you used ... because of ..." would have gotten your message across just as well, if not better...

Comment: @Ray thanks for your answer. The homework is not only this, I also have to use other commands, but I didnt copy the rest of it ,because my concern was about useradd.

Comment: As some who had written homework assignments before, I would suggest you work on your whole assignment first and not worry about this for now.  I know nothing about your course, but I would think it's unlikely you'd be marked down a lot for this one issue.  I personally think it's unavoidable...you're issuing a command for system administration.  A password is required...  I guess you should make sure you haven't misunderstood the question or something.  i.e., maybe the question is asking you what commands to run, but not exactly run them, etc.